# Insert JS at start to Android Webview

Tags: android, android-webview

I've problem with adding Javscript BEFORE page starts to load. I tried to do something like this:

```
@Override
public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
    super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    browser.loadUrl("javascript:alert(window.prepended = 'abc - "+url+"');");
}
```

Or:

```
@Override
public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
    super.onLoadResource(view, url);
    browser.loadUrl("javascript:alert(window.prepended = 'abc - "+url+"');");
}
```

But after first time (when I click `Reload`) I'm getting `undefined` in JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
alert(window.prepended);
setTimeout("alert('Timeout: '+window.prepended)", 2000);
</script>
<a href="?">Reload</a>
```

### Edit:

Finally I used `onProgressChanged` function from `WebChromeClient` :)

Comment: Create a new html file in your cache, and append with your script first. Then read all the content of the page you are loading and write that into new file created. Then load the new file into your webview.

Comment: You mean build-in webview cache? Can I change cache files? I think that this will run page 2 times...

Comment: Trying your suggestion on using onProgressChanged... how do you prevent an infinite loop situation if you call loadUrl inside your onProgressChanged logic?  thx.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this in **onPageStarted()** method:

```
/*
* This call injects JavaScript into the page replacing the page
* content
*/
webView.loadUrl(injectJavaScriptIntoErrorPage());
```

---

```
/**
* Method used to inject custom JavaScript code into HTML page.
* 
* @return String of JavaScript function Called in onReceivedError method
*         for myWebClient
*/
protected String injectJavaScriptIntoErrorPage() {
    String errorPage = "javascript:(function() { "
        + "document.getElementsByTagName('style')[0].innerHTML = ' "
        + " body { margin:auto;width:500px;text-align:center; }"
        + " p { font-size:20px; }'; "
        + "document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML = ' "
        + "  <img src=\"file:///android_asset/custom_error.png\"/>"
        + "  <p>Venter p&#229; nettet.</p>" + "';})()";
    return errorPage;
}
```

---

The method above modifies the current page and it will display an custom error page instead of the default one.
I was calling this in on **onReceivedError()**, but you can you use it in **onPageStarted()** and add your custom javascript function.
This is just to give you an idea on how you can manipulate the current page.

Best regards.

Comment: I have some working page and I have to set some vars before loading. So everything (cookies, ajax, javascript) in current page need to work. Just set some proporties for functions before they use default values.

Comment: You can try to change it's value with something like this:
`document.getElementById('field');"                      "field.value='custom_value';`

Comment: Nothing in JS can help me in this case, trust me ;) After load page - ajax requests was send and any script at this time is pointless.

Comment: Try changing the page in `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()`, and load it again ... I don't have very much experience with JS. Sorry I couldn't be of any more help.